# Invalid preprocessing directive swift

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, objc-bridging-header

I am getting this error(***Invalid preprocessing directive***) while importing payTab's (**Payment Gateway!**)

```
#ifndef PayTabDemo_Bridging_Header_h
#define PayTabDemo_Bridging_Header_h
#import​ <paytabs-iOS/paytabs_iOS.h>
#endif
```